# On windows, git won't sync up correctly if package name got renamed

Tags: windows, git, eclipse

**Old package name:**
package com.packageName;

**New package name:**
package com.packagename;

**Reason for changing name:** Package names are written in all lower case to avoid conflict with the names of classes or interfaces.

**Issue:**  With normal gitpull, git won't identify it as changes and gives error in eclipse. I have noticed this issue solemnly on windows.

**Workaround:** I deleted the folder and ran
`git reset --hard`

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sure, as there are case insensitive (e.g. Windows) and case sensitive file systems. According to the Java naming conventions, it would be `package com.package_name;` (not resulting in any case insensitive vs. sensitive file system issue).

Comment: Why would you even *expect* Git to do this on its own?

Answer (score 0):

You can try and pull again (assuming you have your old repository state back) with first:

```
git config --global core.ignorecase false
```

It should be the default (false), but in your case, check if it was true with:

```
git config --show-scope --show-origin core.ignorecase
```

If not, your workaround was certainly a practical one.